# php regex to remove attributes of html tags except hyper links <a> tags

Tags: php, regex, attributes, preg-replace

Please suggest me PHP regex for preg_replace to remove just all the attributes from HTML tags except `<a>` tag.

I tried already:`preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>',$htmltext);`

It works fine for all the HTML tags but for `<a>` tag it removes href, title and target attributes.

Please suggest me the required changes in above regex or please share the working one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: inb4 `THE PONY HE COMES`.

Comment: @Ben Fortune - what was that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2615209

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to remove all the tags from HTML tags except <a> tag.`

No need of regex, you can just use [strip_tags function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$html = strip_tags($html, '<a>');
```

**UPDATE:** preg_replace to remove just **all the attributes** from HTML tags except from `<a>`. You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
$htmltext = preg_replace("~<(?!a\s)([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(/?)>~i",'<$1$2>', $htmltext);
```

Comment: this is removing all the tags, except <a> tag. I need to keep all the tags with removed atributes. e.g.: `<span style="float:left;">` to just `<span>`. The regex I have given above works fine, but if tag is `<a href="blah blah url">` becomes `<a>` so I need a solution to prevent this `<a href="blah blah url">` tag and it's attributes as is.